# How to get rid of ¶ at end of VARCHAR cell after MySQL DATA LOAD INFILE?

Tags: mysql, csv

I just used mysqlimport to load two columns of values from a .csv file into a VARCHAR field in my table.  The first field is an integer, and the second a VARCHAR, and now see that each of the cells in the second column (the VARCHAR field), contain the symbol "¶" at the end.  The mysqlimport command I used was:

```
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=, --columns='id,name' --local -u username -p database /path/names.csv
```

The .csv file (which I took care to trim before I tried to load it into mysql) looks like:

```
id,name
1,name a
2,name b
3,name c
```

When I query the name field I get, for example, "name a¶". If someone could suggest how to either get rid of this symbol, or import the data in a way that doesn't attach that symbol I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Try `head -5 names.csv | cat -vet` to see if there are weird characters in your CSV file, like `^M`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you, yes, I just tried what you said, and there are weird characters, I suppose because the names are in Vietnamese (e.g. Bắc, Nội), does that mean I should leave the ¶ there, because it shows me since I'm using UTF that the string is longer than I think?

Comment: Mmmmmm.... good luck! I have no idea how to import such things, but have hopefully given you/someone a clue!

Comment: @MarkSetchell you were right.  The problem was the ^M at the end of each line.  When I exported the .csv file from google speadsheets instead of apple numbers they went away, and everything worked fine.  Thanks again for your help!